# 500 server error when debug=False in production

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have been trying for several weeks to resolve an issue with my deployment settings. When debug=True the Heroku app works fine, however, when I change debug to =False I always get a 500 server error. I have tried every suggestion on the other stackoverflow threads regarding this issue and none seem to work for me. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

```
"""
Django settings for scipertise_demo project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

#API_KEY ='46235562'

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!

SECRET_KEY = 'SECRET_KEY'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'pages',
    'users',
    'search',
    'taggit',
    'booking',
    'bootstrap4',
    'bootstrap_datepicker_plus',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'sendgrid',





]

#HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
#    'default': {
#        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch2_backend.Elasticsearch2SearchEngine',
#        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
#        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
#    },
#}

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
BOOTSTRAP4 = {
    'include_jquery': True,
}

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'scipertise_demo.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'scipertise_demo.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases
#DATABASES = {
#    'default': dj_database_url.config(
#        default=config('DATABASE_URL')
#    )
#}

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
#MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media/')

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

TAGGIT_CASE_INSENSITIVE = True

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'EMAIL_HOST_USER'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True


SENDGRID_API_KEY='SENDGRID_API_KEY'
SENDGRID_PASSWORD='SENDGRID_PASSWORD'
SENDGRID_USERNAME='SENDGRID_USERNAME'


# Activate Django-Heroku.
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Comment: Did you try and host your static content from another source? When debug is set to false it might be that your static home is not being served.

Comment: what is the error? Please share traceback from logs if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by another source? I have all my static files contained within my django project in the static folder and set the static root. How would I serve my static home?

Answer (score 0):

Enable white noise in the middleware.

http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html

Comment: I tried this but still getting the error. Did you follow all of the other steps to configure your static files with whitenoise?

Comment: To deploy in heroku, I followed this tutorial - https://medium.com/agatha-codes/9-straightforward-steps-for-deploying-your-django-app-with-heroku-82b952652fb4

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps someone. The problem for me was the forward slash in '/css/layout.css' in my html template (I know.. I'm banging my head against a wall) and commenting out the line: STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage' in my settings file. Worked perfectly after those two changes.